# How to select a value in select options by passing key in jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a requirement of appointments from each department.Appointments are done using plugin. While clicking on appointment the department name should be selected in the select dropdown of the plugin.

This is my code:

```
<a href="appointments/?$key=<?=$dept->post_title;?>" class="btn btn-default">Make Appointment</a>
```

this is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var key="<?=$_GET['key']?>";
        console.log(key);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    //jQuery('#custom_service_names').find('option[text="<?=$_GET['key']?>"]').attr('selected',true);
                    jQuery('#custom_service_names').find('option').each(function(){
                     console.log(this.text);
                     if(key == this.text){
                        jQuery('#custom_service_names').find('option[this.text="<?=$_GET['key']?>"]').attr('selected',true);
                        jQuery(this).attr('selected',true);
                        alert(jQuery(this));
                     }
                  });
                    jQuery('option[value="<?=$_GET['key']?>"]').attr('selected',true);
            },500);
    });


</script>
```

the key is passed. the values are also displayed in loop. But the value dosent get selected though. can anyone help me

Comment: Should "<?=$_GET['key']?>" match the value or the text of the option?

Comment: key value should match any of the text in options to display the key value as selected

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var key="<?=$_GET['key']?>";
        var nkey=0;
setTimeout(function(){
jQuery('#custom_service_names').find('option').each(function(){
if(key == jQuery(this).text()){
                        console.log(jQuery(this).val());
                        nkey=jQuery(this).val();
                     }
});
                    jQuery('option[value="'+nkey+'"]').attr('selected',true);
            },1000);
    });
</script>
```

all i did is that i stored the option value into a variable and made that variable append onto my jquery line